# how to allow CORS /Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery

sorry for the stupid question, but how to I allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin?"

I want page A  (the page I am getting content from) to allow page B(where I need content pulled into) access. It's weird they are both on the same server one is a wordpress page and one is static.. not sure where the code is supposed to go to make this happen.

Comment: Do you need IE support? jquery doesn't support CORS requests in IE<10 without a plugin.

Comment: yea probably.. what I don't understand is why it would not work when the pages are from the SAME domain.. ie. my domain.com/a and my domain.com/b.php...

Comment: That should work fine. What exactly are the two different urls? cross-origin means different domain, subdomain, protocol, or port. For example, `http://foo.com` `https://foo.com` `http://foo.com:8965` `http://bar.foo.com` are all cross-origin from each other, even if they all point to the same ip/server

Comment: www.mysite.com/accolades
www.mysite.com/brews.php

Comment: Then you shouldn't be having a cross-origin problem. Does any part of your site use https?

Comment: thats what I don't get at all, it's working then it's not.. really weird..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24335/discussion-between-deedub-and-kevin-b)

Comment: what is weird is that WHEN there is an error it does show one page as http://mydomain.com and then http://www.mydomain.com so sometimes it's www and sometimes its not

Comment: Then that would be the cross-origin problem. `http://www.foo.com` != `http://foo.com` I suggest redirecting all requests to one or the other.

Comment: ok.. that makes sense.. how would I go about doing that..BTW.. thanks for you time I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure, there's several ways to do it. htaccess, iis redirection, dns redirect, etc. Or, you could NOT redirect and point to your target using a relative path rather than including the domain in the path.

Comment: using relative paths worked... consitnatly at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest modifying the url option to a relative path to avoid this issue.

```
$.ajax(function(){
    url: /*"http://www.mydomain.com*/"/foo.html",
    ....
});
```