# how to allow CORS for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, cors

I have a problem trying to make a request from JS/Ajax to my WebAPI. In my solution I have a Web API that is published on srv02:2400 and my website that is published on srv02:2300

When I navigate to the page http://srv02:2300/all-requests.aspx, the page is loading fine except the data that is supposed to come form my API

and I am getting the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://srv02:2400/api/requests/find/1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://srv02:2300' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

However, If I take the url http://srv02:2400/api/requests/find/1 and paste it in a browser, it is getting me the correct JSON list!.

I tried to enable the CORS globally as it is recommended [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors) in my API by:

1. Installing the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. Updating my WebApiConfig.cs by addding the following:

   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://srv02:2400", "*", "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);

However, this did not work.

As I mentioned before, I am doing my request as Ajax reqeusts

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://srv02:2400/api/requests/find/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (requests) {
             console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried to change json to jsonp as it is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818498/how-to-allow-cors-access-control-allow-origin) but it did not work.

Any idea of how to solve the problem here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global attribute looks wrong.

I think you want two things to change.

- Your CORS url should be the URL of the application you want to allow (not your apis url) ie `:2300` not `:2400`.
- You have selected no valid headers and methods (verbs). You either need to use specific values here, or * (which probably makes more sense if you are applying this globally).

eg you want the following:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://srv02:2300", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

this should instruct browsers (using the OPTIONS response) that if they want to call this API from `http://srv02:2300/*` with any verbs or headers, its ok. If another domain tries to call this API it will not be ok.