# Displaying 400 (bad request) in browser console when performing post method through API in angular 6

Tags: angular

showing 400 (bad request) when performing post method through REST API

this is for a SQL server, running ASP.net.

**rest service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';**

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

var httpoptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}

@Injectable({

providedIn: 'root'

})
```

**employee component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {RestService} from  '../rest.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public rs:RestService) { }
employees:any

  ngOnInit() {

    this.funget()
  }

funget(){
    this.rs.getemployee().subscribe(employees=>{
      this.employees=employees
    })
}

insert;t1;t2;t3;t4;t5;t6;t7;t8;
  funins(){

    var data={
      ID:this.t1, Name:this.t2,Gender:this.t3,Designation:this.t4,Department:this.t5,EmailID:this.t6,
      PhoneNo: this.t7,Address:this.t8}
    this.rs.insertemployee(data).subscribe(dt=>{
      this.insert=JSON.parse(dt)
      this.funget()
    })
  }
```

***employee controller.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using SampleAPI.Models;
namespace SampleAPI.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:52821", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
         IEmployeeRepository repository = new EmployeeRepository();
        [HttpGet, Route("GetEmployee")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {
            return repository.GetAll();
        }
        [HttpGet, Route("GetEmployeeBYID")]
        public Employee GetEmployee(int ID)
        {
            Employee emp = repository.Get(ID);
            if (emp == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return emp;
        }
        [HttpPost,Route("InsertEmployee")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Employee emp)
        {
            emp = repository.Insert(emp);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.Created, emp);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { customerID = emp.ID });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
        //http://localhost:52821/UpdateEmployee?ID=3
        [HttpPut,Route("UpdateEmployee")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployee(int ID,Employee emp)
        {
            emp.ID = ID;
            if (!repository.Update(emp))
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, " ID :" + ID);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
        [HttpDelete,Route("DeleteEmployee")]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEmployee(int ID)
        {
            Employee emp = repository.Get(ID);
            if (emp == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                if (repository.Delete(ID))
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 
                        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, " ID " + ID);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

**i expect the output of my post data through API, but showing 
OPTIONS http://localhost:52821/InsertEmployee 400 (Bad Request)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:52821/InsertEmployee' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

core.js:12501 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", URL: null, Ok: false, …}**

Answer (score 0):

The problem stay in Backend, enable CORS policy in your server.

The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options for the target resource. The client can specify a URL for the OPTIONS method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://srv02:2300", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

[how to allow CORS for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497075/how-to-allow-cors-for-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually represents some kind of faulty data that you have passed. It can be because some integer field value is float, or integer field value is string, etc. CORS error is bit complicated to understand but if it comes with some other error then its usually not because of CORS blocking on server.

I recommend you use postman and send Employee data in body. Try to remove one one property to identify which exact data format is wrong.